# Convert Calender to Date according to timezone

Tags: java, timezone

I wrote a code where Calender was prepared according to time zone.

```
 Calendar toDayDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(appTheme.getTimezoneId()));

Date formattedSelectedDate = toDayDateCalendar.getTime();
```

But I am getting the "formattedSelectedDate" according to System.i want to get the date according to timezone.How can i get it.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

(A) A `java.util.Date` object, despite the name, represents a date and a time-of-day as seen in UTC. A `Date` does not have a time zone. Well, actually it does down deep, but for our purpose here that is irrelevant.

So your expectation of "i want to get the date according to timezone" makes no sense.

(B) You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Never use `Calendar`, never use `Date`, never use `TimeZone`.

Get the current moment as seen in a particular time zone.

```java
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime nowTunis = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ) ;
```

If you want the date-only, without a time-of-day and without a time zone, use `LocalDate`.

```java
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate todayTokyo = LocalDate.now( zoneId ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: If you want the date-only, without a time-of-day and without a time zone, use LocalDate.What did you mean "without a time zone".

Comment: @user3692033 A `LocalDate` has simply a year, a month, and a day-of-month. But no time zone. For example, “January 23, 2021”, `LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 )`. We do not know if that means the 23rd in Tokyo Japan or the 23rd in Toledo Ohio US — two dates that happen at very different times, several hours difference. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. The day in Japan starts and ends much earlier than in the US mainland. Additionally, the day can vary in length if we account for time zone, because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Comment: can we set different timezone to a LocalDate?

Comment: No, @user3692033, a `LocalDate` hasn’t got a time zone, so that would not make sense. Why would you have wanted to do that? Asking because there surely is a way to obtain your end goal with java.time.